# Как добавить свою html страницу в laravel?

Tags: laravel, mvc, route

Ранее не сталкивался с laravel, архитектуру не знаю. Знаю что нужно придерживаться паттерну mvc. Подскажите куда закинуть путь url, и саму верстку, чтобы при обращений к url например /test/ открывалась верстка?
P.S Нашел папку `resources/views/` видимо туда кидать верстку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас либо есть контроллер **app/Http/Controllers/ControllerNameController.php** и в нём есть соответствующая функция которая возвращает View

```
public function actionName(Request $request): View
{
    return view('template.name');
}
```

И на него должен светиться роут к примеру в **routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/url', [\App\Http\Controllers\ControllerNameController::class, 'actionName']);
```

Либо у вас роут соответствующий

```
Route::view('/url', 'template.name');
```

При этом у вас в папке **resources/views/template** должен быть файл с вёрсткой **name.blade.php**